# how to check a byte inside of stream of bytes using bitmask

Tags: java, binary, bitmask

I have `bytebuffer` and I am reading 8 bytes(long) per iteration I have bitmask that I would like to compare but I am not sure what my pattern should look like. For example,

```
private final static long ASCII_125 = 0x7D;

public static boolean isValidPath(
        DirectBuffer path)
{
  boolean isPathValid = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < path.capacity(); i += Long.BYTES)
  {
      long charsLong = path.getLong(i);
      if ((charsLong & result) != xxxxxx(pattern))
      {
          isPathValid = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  return isPathValid;
}
```

So if the charlong is `0b01111011_01111011_00100101_00100101_01111011_01111011_01111101_01111101` and to check if `01111101` byte exists in this 8 bytes. I guess I need to find patterns that will logically let me check multiple values at once, construct a mask for that pattern then apply the mask to all 8 bytes at once. But I am having trouble coming up with the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

This basically checks each byte by shifting the long right 8 bits and masking it off to
a byte.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < path.capacity(); i += Long.BYTES) { 
      long charsLong = path.getLong(i);
      while(charsLong > 0) {
          // get low order byte
          byte val = (byte)(charLong&0xFF);
          if ((val & result) != xxxxxx(pattern)) {
             return false;
          }
          // right shift thru sign bit by 8 bits 
          charsLong>>>= 8; 
      }
   }
   return true;
```

Note that if you are checking for a specific byte value, you can just compare each byte to the result byte. But if you want to check and see if certain bits are set in the bytes then you need a bit mask.

E.g.  To see if the lower order 101 bits are set you would do the following.

```
byte bitMask = 0b101;

if ((test & bitMask) == bitMask) {
   bits are set.
}
```

Comment: thanks @WJS let me take a look just FYI the reason why I am converting it to long is that instead of checking 1 byte at time I want to check 8 bytes per iteration.